# Xcode 7 does not show function callers for swift 2

Tags: swift2, xcode7

Looks like index is kinda broken. How to fix this?
**P.S.** Function, of course, is getting called multiple times.

**UPD:**
Works in Xcode 7.3

[image]

Comment: same problem here...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looks like it's not implemented yet in the menu, but you can get the same result by selecting the function or method and **right-clicking to select** `Find Call Hierarchy`.

I found this in [Apple's release notes for XCode 7](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/xc7_release_notes.html).

Comment: This was working, but in newer XCode releases (like 7.3 (7D175) which I have now), it doesn't work.  Bah!

Comment: This works in the present App Store version of Xcode for Yosemite: Version 7.2.1 (7C1002).  Thanks.